# Execute a method right before execution of various methods in different classes using Java

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, aop

I am facing a code design challenge and not very sure how to resolve it. I tried researching a bit on the net, but that made me even more confused.

InterfaceI1 -> Parent level interface (Single method)

```java
interface I1 {

print(String a);

}
```

Class C1 -> C1 implements I1 (C1 overrides method from I1 has no method of its own)

```java
public class C1 implements I1 {

@Override
print(String a){
//some code
}

}
```

Class CC1, CC2, CC3, CC4, CC5 -> All these extend C1 (Overrides method in C1 and has methods of its own as well). They are not Spring beans.

```java
public class CC1 extends C1 {

@Override
print(String a) {

//Some Code
}

//Need to execute common code on initiation of this method/
//Similar methods are in CC2, CC3 etc
scan() {
//Some Code
}

}
```

I need to execute a piece of code on execution of certain methods like scan() in classes CC1, CC2, CC3, CC4, CC5. These methods have nothing in common and certainly it's not an overridden method.

Is there a way to write this common piece of code in a central place and make it execute on execution of concerned methods?

Also the execution of this common piece of code would also depend on another environmental condition. For example:

```
If the method scan() in CC1 is executed  &&  its a weekend
{
   Execute the common code
}
```

Since I don't want to clutter all the methods with the same boilerplate code, I did some research and came across AOP. It looked like a fit for the requirement, though I'm not sure if conditional execution could be managed with AOP. As I was reading about it, I learned about the *Action At a Distance* anti-pattern and how its not good for the code maintainability.

Any leads or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: After reading it, I don't understand what you want.Can you not bother, provide some pseudo-code and comments, at least write down which "classes" you use, like this `interface parent {void SingleMethod();}`

Comment: Hope the edits would give more details  @时间只会一直走

Comment: Native AspectJ is what you want, not Spring AOP. You already mentioned that you want to intercept methods of non-Spring beans. Read an AspectJ tutorial and try. Good luck. If then, you have a concrete problem with the AspectJ syntax or whatever, feel free to ask a new question, but not one consisting of snippets out of context and vague prose, but a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let other people see what you tried. They are not supposed to write your code for you, but to help you fix yours. SO ist not some free version of Upwork.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a rough implementation（according to my understanding）！

Based on the following structure：

```
interface I1 {
    void print(String a);
}

class C1 implements I1 {
    @Override
    public void print(String a) {
        //some code
    }
}

class CC1 extends C1 {
    public void scan_CC1() {
        System.out.println("the scan method of CC1");
    }
}

class CC2 extends C1 {
    public void scan_CC2() {
        System.out.println("the scan method of CC2");
    }
}

class CCN extends C1 {
    public void scan_CCN() {
        System.out.println("the scan method of CCN");
    }
}
```

First，write a Cell class,It will be a container for the method：

```
class Cell {
    public I1 obj;
    public Method method;
    public Function<String, Boolean> priorityCall;
    public String param;
    public Cell(I1 obj, Method method, Function<String, Boolean> priorityCall, String param) {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.method = method;
        this.priorityCall = priorityCall;
        this.param = param;
    }
    public Cell(I1 obj, Method method) {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.method = method;
    }
}
```

It contains two construction methods:

- construction method with four parameters, which is used to handle method calls with special needs, such as the scan method of CC1 you mentioned, which needs to be executed on weekends.
- Another construction method, containing two parameters, calls a method with no special requirements

Next provide a class for registering methods（you can find a suitable place to add the public execution method in the run method）：

```
class Register {
    List<Cell> registerCells = new ArrayList<>();
    public void reg(Cell cell) {
        registerCells.add(cell);
    }

    public void run() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        for (int i = 0; i < registerCells.size(); i++) {
            Cell c = registerCells.get(i);
            // todo::
            //     here you can execute that piece of code
            if (c.priorityCall == null) {
                c.method.invoke(c.obj);
            } else {
                boolean flag = c.priorityCall.apply(c.param);
                if (flag) {
                    c.method.invoke(c.obj);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Through the `reg` method, you can register the method that needs to be called, and then execute it through the `run` method.

Then to register and run

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Register register = new Register();
    // scan_CC1 can only be called on weekends
    Cell cell_CC1 = new Cell(new CC1(), CC1.class.getMethod("scan_CC1"), "weekend"::equals, "weekend");
    // scan_CC1 can only be called on monday
    Cell cell_CC2 = new Cell(new CC2(), CC2.class.getMethod("scan_CC2"), "monday"::equals, "sunday");
    // scan_CCN no limit
    Cell cell_CCN = new Cell(new CCN(), CCN.class.getMethod("scan_CCN"));

    register.reg(cell_CC1);
    register.reg(cell_CC2);
    register.reg(cell_CCN);
    register.run();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As what I have learnt, Spring AOP is perfect for your problem. In fact, AOP is designed to solve this problem, and AOP is an important feature of Spring. I highly recommend you learn Spring for long run in your career as Spring/Spring Boot is a highly used framework.

And if you have not time or not interested in it, you can create a new class and a new method in this class. In this method you write the common code. And then in your classes, you create an object of that class, and you call that method in your class CC1, CC2, etc.

Comment: As i mentioned in the question later CC1, CC2 etc are not spring beans so i wont be able to use spring aop. AspectJ seems to be a suitable candidate though.

Comment: Also just wondering what would be the performance impact of it since i will introducing a lot of aspecj components here for eg :  the aspectj compiler ajc @

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).